# Excel rank values but ignore some on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to add a rank to the following columns:

[image]

The rank value should be based on `col2`, but only if a few conditions are met.

1. value of `col1` must be `>= 0.1`
2. value in `col2` must be numeric

Given these criteria, the final ranking should be this:

[image]

For criteria 2 the following formula did work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),1+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,">"&B2),"")
```

but as soon as I want to add the first criteria I am stuck. I would have thought the formula

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),A2>0.1),1+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,">"&B2),"")
```

would solve the issue, but now the rank increases even if `col1` is below 0.1. What do I need to do to get the desired result?

Comment: You have to manually select all those non continuous cells and then proceed with the rank. Can't be done by dragging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a helper column to determine the items that need to be ranked, then another column to do the ranking. I wasn't able to combine the formulas into 1 cell, but there may be a way. Anyway this is what it looks like:

[image]

Which results in:

[image]

Please note this is new functionality with spilled arrays, so may not work on your version of excel. I believe modification to CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER array is how you would implement this in older versions of excel.

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar. I added a helper column to determine if a rank should be assigned. And if that was true, then the value was taken into the rank determination